# TCP Model Control

Tags: gazebo-plugin

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello, I am new to using Gazebo and was hoping to get some help getting started. I am looking to control a model simulated in Gazebo, as well as read sensor information, over TCP with another program (written in c++) running on Ubuntu 12.10. I have seen the example on subscribing to a topic, but I was hoping to find an example on publishing a topic, and how to create the corresponding plugin in Gazebo that would control the model.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/971/tcp-model-control/) by [JSenna](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/168/jsenna/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 11 on 2013-01-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I hope the following link will help you.
[Publishing a topic over Gazebo Simulator](http://pastebin.com/YLue8A0z)

Try to follow the gazebo's tutorials: http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials#Controlling_a_Robot

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Vaz](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/171/daniel-vaz/) with karma: 305 on 2013-01-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-01-30**:
Another tutorial: http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.4/custom_messages